# Driver Mysql in WildFly 18 WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed

Tags: mysql, wildfly

I´m trying to configure wildfly 18 with mysql. I´ve installed the module, and it says:

```
    18:19:20,049 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "inventarioDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.inventarioDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/inventarioDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
    ]
}
18:19:20,182 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "inventarioDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"
    ],
```

Here is my standalone:

```
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                </driver>



            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/inventarioDS" pool-name="inventarioDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventario</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>xxxxx</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

The module is correctly installed in the modules folder. When i go to the admin consolo i see the datasource but the test fails.

Comment: Where is your module located and what does the `module.xml` file look like? Here's a CLI example for postgresql https://gist.github.com/jamezp/3d3fe3bf57fe99ea91c1.

Comment: <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.43-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
 <module name="javax.api"/>
 <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module> -- it is on the com.mysql folder

Comment: It should be in a directory like `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/mysql/main` which should have the library and the `module.xml` file.

Comment: Sorry the path is like you wrote, and the library is on the same folder.

Comment: Maybe try removing the `driver-class` from the `datasource` since it's already defined on the `driver`.

Comment: I´ve removed it , but now the logs says: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora de verano romance' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know that's the issue then. I would hope for a better error :)